# cannot import payfort library in my project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, payfort

am trying to integrate PayFort IOS SDK into my project ...

i followed the steps in their document which is: https://docs.payfort.com/pdf/FORT_Mobile-SDK_iOS_Integration_Guide_v_2.8.pdf

but when i reach step 5.3 point 1 .. i will not be able to import it and i will get this error ...

[image]

and only can import:

[image]

how to solve this and continue?

Comment: If you have followed the same steps then it must work as it is working for me here

Comment: Set -Objc in the Other Linker Flags in the Target -> Build Settings Tab.

Comment: @PPL still getting the same error! :(

Comment: It is working on my side

Comment: @PPL same document version?

Comment: Section 4.1. Fort Mobile SDK

Comment: @PPL it starts from 5.2 actually .. right?

Comment: Yes, please find the line "Extract the folder found in section 4.1" and tap on section 4.1

Comment: @PPL i just tried from 0 .. but got this error: /Users/lamatatwany/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/payforttest2-gskjtrbpjnzbdzcordtakffstgjq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/payforttest2.app/Frameworks/PayFortSDK.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Comment: clean build the project

Comment: @PPL just did and same :(

Comment: 1. Delete Derived data
2. Clean the project

Comment: @PPL same error T_T

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171218/discussion-between-ppl-and-mrs-bassim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I got source code from you, I found the mistake what you are doing. Please find below.

Please set **Objective-C Bridging Header** to following value.

```
payforttest2-Bridging-Header.h
```

and try again adding **PayFortSDK.framework** and **PayFortSDK.bundle**.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!